# OPENCV Best way to handle a game screenshot

Tags: computer-vision, opencv, python

I want to make an application for counting game statistics automatically. For that purpose, I need some sort of computer vision for handling screenshots of the game.

There are bunch of regions with different skills in always the same place that app needs to recognize. I assume that it should have a database of pictures or maybe some trained samples.

I've started to learn opencv lib, but not sure what will be better for this purpouse.

Would you please give me some hints or algorithms that I could use?

Here is the example of game screenshot.

[image]

Comment: If sizes, orientations and positions don't change, template matching on subimages will work great

Comment: To read text, it is common to use [pytesseract](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract) to perform OCR. To read the individual icons, [template matching](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html) is probably the way to go. Template matching will be complicated by a semi-transparent background and different colors.

Comment: @Micka @bfris Thanks, guys! Actually, template matching with `TM_SQDIFF_NORMED` and blur works fine with that image.

Answer (score 0):

You can covert it into gray scale and then use any haar cascade classifier to read the words in that image and then save it into any file format (csv) this way you can utilize your game pics for gathering data so that you can train your models